# Creating a transparent UIview

Tags: ios, xcode

Unfortunately it is not completely clear what I am trying to do from the title. I want to create an interactive tutor for my IOS application. At the moment I have a simple UIviewcroller with some images, but I want to make it more interactive. I want to add ontop of my normal UIview a second UIview which is partially transparent to enable the user to see what there is below it, and in some parts, invisible. there are the parts that the user has to touch. on this UIview there will be arrows, labels, and other information. Is this possible? If a UIview is covered by another, can I make it possible for the user to interact with parts of the one below it?

Comment: Please write the reason for downgrading

Comment: +1 because this is a relevant question. Hate how spiteful SO has become. I've seen people ask so many relevant thoughtful questions lately, that have been greeted with animosity, downgrades and ridicule. There is such a thing as humility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` to disable interaction.

And `view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` for a transparent background.

Touches will go right through the view to the next one below it.

**EDIT:**

Alternatively you could try setting `view.alpha = 0.0f;`. This will make the view transparent. Then you add any buttons and labels to this view. These buttons will be visible and work as expected, but tapping anywhere else will pass through the transparent view. If alpha is below some threshold (not sure about the exact value), touches are ignored and passed to the next view.

Comment: but if I want to disable interaction on only one part of the UIview and not all of it?

Comment: Can I set some sort of coordinates for user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

On the subview you want transparent set userInteractionEnabled = FALSE. You can also do the same thing with UIWebVIew, UIImageView, etc. also you can set the background color to UIColor clear color. That way it's see through to the layers below.

Comment: `FALSE` is called `NO` in Objective-C.

Comment: Let me know if both false, no and 0 produce the same results. ;)

Comment: point of the above exercise is all three are acceptable for this property.

Comment: It's a convention, not a syntax error. You'll almost never see true/false in Obj-C code.

Comment: To each their own. They each respectively evaluate to 0 or 1 in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try making top view transparent and add a third view below and make its bg-color black and set alpha 0.5